# Copy-visible for hideshow mode?

Tags: code-folding, kill-ring, hideshow

Is there an analog of `org-copy-visible` for hideshow minor mode?

An example use case is: enter Python file -> hide all top-level -> copy visible and now I have a list of top-level defs in the kill ring.

I'm open to suggestions of a better alternative to hideshow mode also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `org-copy-visible` itself. AFAICT, it does not place any requirements on the buffer (e.g. it does not require that it should be an Org mode buffer). In light testing, it seems to work: I open a python file with a few `def`s, I enable `hs-minor-mode`, I do `hs-hide-all`, select a region (there are other visible things at thισ point, not just the `def`s, so selecting a region allows skipping those), then call `org-copy-visible` and paste the list in another buffer.

No guarantees, but maybe it will work well enough for your purposes.